# C# Bringing non modal form in front of modal form?

Tags: c#, winforms

In our app we have a form that can be opened up non-modally. We have another form that can be opened up modally.

From the modal form you can click a button to open up the non-modal form. This works fine, you can then mess about with both the modal and non-modal form.

However, if the non-modal form was opened up before the modal one, then the non-modal form can no longer be accessed until the modal form is closed.

Is there anyway, short of closing and re-opening the non-modal form that I can bring the non-modal form to the front from the modal form??

Thanks

Comment: if you need both windows open and accessible at the same time, modal windows are a bad choice.

Comment: short answer is no - what you are saying is "If have a system which enforces 'A'. I don't want 'A' can I still use this system but not get it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the expected behaviour.

If "A" is non-modal and "B" is modal then:

Opening "B" then "A" will mean that both forms can be accessed as the last opened form is non-modal.

Opening "A" then "B" will mean that only "B" can be accessed as the last opened form is modal.

So if you want both forms to be accessible regardless of the order they were opened you will need to make both non-modal.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from incorrect use of the Modal concept. The best thing would be to rethink the whole design. A modal Form should perform a Dialog with the user and normally only open up other Modal Forms. And even that is a questionable choice.

Having said that, you could try re-parenting the non-modal Form when the Modal one comes up.

Comment: I am aware of the design flaws.. I just need to get this working.

Reparenting the form doesnt work. It just embeds the non-modal form within the modal form.. a cool effect, but not what I need.